# Calling recursive function twice consecutively

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 16

void makeBranches(int, int);
void display(int, int);

int main(){

  makeBranches(0, LENGTH-1);
}

void makeBranches(int left, int right){

  if(left >= right){
    return;
  } else{
    display(left, right);
    makeBranches(left, (right+left)/2);
    makeBranches((right+left/2)+1, right);
  }
}

void display(int left, int right){
  printf("%d, %d", left, right);
  int mid = (left+right)/2;
  int i;

  for(i = left; i <= right; i++){
    if(i == mid)
      printf("X");
    else
      printf("-");
  }

  if(right == LENGTH-1)
    printf("\n");

}
```

The problem that I am having is the second call of makeBranches only executes with the values that caused the first call of makeBranches to return and not the original values that the first call used.

Comment: Maybe the second call should be `makeBranches((right+left)/2+1, right);` ?

Answer (score 3):

I agree. Your parentheses are different between the first call of `makeBranches(left, (right+left)/2);` is correct - the second call of `makeBranches((right+left/2)+1, right);` includes the `/2` inside the parentheses, which screws up the order of operations.

Change the second line to `makeBranches((right+left)/2+1, right);` as suggested and then take a look at the values.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making sense.  C passes parms by value, so the parms seen by the second call cannot be modified by the first call.

But with recursive functions it's very easy to get confused with where you are in the call depth.  Try passing & displaying a 3rd depth parameter:

```
void makeBranches(int left, int right, int depth){

  if(left >= right){
    return;
  } else{
    display(left, right, depth);
    makeBranches(left, (right+left)/2, depth+1);
    makeBranches((right+left/2)+1, right, depth+1);
  }
}
```

So you can keep track of how deep you are in the call stack.  You could also pass a parm indicating if it's the "left" call or the "right" call.

Comment: Still: "*Maybe the second call should be `makeBranches((right+left)/2+1, right);`?*"

Comment: @alk -- Could be.  I'm just trying to explain how to debug the program.  Solve the problem and they don't learn anything.  Help them solve the problem and they learn.

Comment: I totally agree .... Referring this approach: Is there any FAQ here on SO how to learn `gdb` and when to use?

Comment: @alk -- SO doesn't do FAQs.  Try to start one and you'll get beat up.