# Output of function with 2 consecutive recursive statements

Tags: python, recursion

I am struggling to understand the output of a recursive function that calls itself twice. I understand that a function with this kind of structure is unlikely to ever be needed in practice, but as I'm new to programming, I thought it'd be helpful for me to understand the concept of recursion in a little more depth. I also have (I think) no trouble understanding the concept of recursion in a simpler case, i.e., factorial, Fibonacci seq.

I have run this through python tutor and attempted to use a debugger, but I'm afraid I still don't quite understand what is happening behind the scenes.

I have also searched this site, and although one or two people have asked similar questions, the answers given were not helpful for my case e.g. [Calling recursive function twice consecutively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211969/calling-recursive-function-twice-consecutively)

```py
def recurse(n, s):
    if n == 0:
        print(s)
    else:
        recurse(n - 1, n + s)
        recurse(n - 1, n + 2*s)

recurse(2, 0)
```

This is what I thought was happening:

- recurse(2, 0)

  - 2 != 0, so pass along to else:
  - recurse(1,2)

    - 1 != 0, so pass along to else:
    - recurse(0, 3)

      - 0 == 0, so print(3)
  - recurse(1, 2)

    - 1 != 0, so pass along to else:
    - recurse(0, 5)

      - 0 == 0, so print(5)

So the output I expect is `3, 5` but the output I get is `3, 5, 3, 5`

Does the second `recurse` call then call the first? I had thought that 2 consecutive recursive statements executed independently, but that does not seem to be the case here.

Any help pointing out what exactly it is that I am not understanding would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `recurse(1, 2)` calls `recurse(0, 3)` *and then* `recurse(0, 5)`. Then `recurse(1, 2)` is called again, which calls `recurse(0, 3)` and `recurse(0, 5)` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happening:

- recurse(2, 0)

  - 2 != 0, so pass along to else:
  - recurse(1, 2)

    - 1 != 0, so pass along to else:
    - recurse(0, 3)

      - 0 == 0, so print(3)
    - recurse(0, 5) **// You missed recurse(n - 1, n + 2*s)**

      - 0 == 0, so print(5)
  - recurse(1, 2)

    - 1 != 0, so pass along to else:
    - recurse(0, 3) **// You missed recurse(n - 1, n + s)**

      - 0 == 0, so print(3)
    - recurse(0, 5)

      - 0 == 0, so print(5)

Comment: Thank you! That really clears things up :) (Also tried to upvote but too little reputation, sorry :( )

Comment: No problem! Keep practicing!